# How can MockMvc get around API exceptions?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockmvc

Ideally, I want this:

```
    @Test
    void testWelcome() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/oups"))
            .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
    }
```

But the test fails because it throws at `get("/oops")` (which runs a controller method that throws a RuntimeException) before it can get to the assertion. How do I deal with this issue? This is my quick fix for now:

```
    @Test
    void testTriggerException() throws Exception {
        try {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/oops"))
            .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        fail();
    }
```

Comment: How have you setup your test? It should do default error handling, so it looks like you haven't setup your test properly. Please add your full test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Assertions
    .assertThatThrownBy(
                    () -> mockMvc.perform(get("/oops").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)))
    .hasCauseInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class)
    .hasMessageContaining("The exception message");
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it still possible to check the status code?

Comment: Sadly I'm not sure about the status.. hope this was helpful

Comment: This shouldn't bee needed when MockMvc has properly been setup (or rather the test case).